# How do i get the batch compute environment name when i create through cdk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-batch

I am creating the AWS batch Job using CDK. I am creating the compute environment without giving giving the name.The compute environment gets created with random characters. I wanted to know how i can get the name of the compute environment to use in the job queue programatically.

Thanks

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it with [computeEnvironmentName](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_batch/ComputeEnvironment.html#aws_cdk.aws_batch.ComputeEnvironment.compute_environment_name). For example:

```
CfnOutput(self, "compute environment", value=computeEnv.compute_environment_name)
```